# Best Approach to use [Column] or [ColumnAttribute] DataAnnotation in ASP.Net Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I am new to asp.net core MVC framework(Before this I was using Laravel.)

I have a two table, Country and State, I will use InnerJoin to join those both table.

In my CountryModel, I have 4 property like below

```
public int CountryId { get; set; }

public string CountryName { get; set; }

public int StateId { get; set; }

public string StateList { get; set; }



SELECT c.CountryId,
       c.CountryName,
       s.StateId,
       s.States AS 'StateName'
       FROM _tbAddr_Country AS c
       INNER JOIN _tbAddr_State AS s on s.CountryId = c.CountryId
```

The above is my sql query, in my Country Model property I have no "StateName" property but I have "StateList", I just want to map "StateList" to "StateName" by using DataAnnotation just like below, I have tried

```
[ColumnAttribute("StateName")]
public string StateList { get; set; }
```

And

```
[Column("StateName")]
public string StateList { get; set; }
```

These two is not working for me, I know I can solve this problem by simply change the "StateList" to "StateName", But I hope I can find alternative way like use "Column" or "ColumnAttribute" Data Annotation to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

P/S: I using .net core 1.1 and SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Comment: Are you using correct nuget package please cross check from here http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=ColumnAttribute

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How do I make sure I am using the correct package? Because I new to asp.net core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not working the way you think.

Column must match a table column name. You however have a projection using a join. So there is no table with such a name.

EntityFramework Core 1.x and 2.0 doesn't support ad-hoc mapping from Views or queries to an arbitrary model. This feature is currently on [roadmap for 2.1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap) as "[Read-only view types in the model](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9290)".

Please note that this feature is located in the "stretch goal" section. It means, it's prioritized for 2.1, but changes are that not all of the goals will make it to 2.1 release and may be pushed to the next version if it's not done by the time 2.1 gets released (which should be around the time when ASP.NET Core 2.1 and/or .NET Core 2.1 releases)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I did not using EF Core, I using Sql Servre Express as my database.

Comment: @noleavename: I am not talking about your database, I speak about the ORM you are using. The Sql Client and ADO.NET don't have any ORM functionality, so you can't magically map from SQL to a C# model class without an ORM framework (EF Core, Dapper, NHibernate, etc.)

Comment: Oh I see, so the only way I have is rename the property in model?

Comment: Currently, with EF Core (if you use `DbContext`, it's EF or EF Core - Entity Framework) - either 1.x or 2.0 - you **can't** do ad-hoc mappings. For EF Core up to 2.0 you entity has to **match the table** and it's column. MicroORMs such as Dapper don't have such limitations. Of course you can use plain ADO.NET and SQL Client, then you can do joins too, but they can't/won't be mapped to POCO classes and you got to use Sql reader and Indexers to access its content. You lose the strong typing this way